# Using jquery to add options to select element within cloned table row causes select options outside the cloned element to be modified

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

I'm trying to use a table row as a template for adding multiple rows.  I need to clone the row, then update the select elements with some data.  I hide the table row template before I do the clone, so the selects should not show up for the time being.

The issue I'm having is that I have other selects defined on the page that are being modified by this process, but when I do the following:

```
clonedTr.find('select').each(function() {
    console.log($(this));
    ...
```

it confirms that I am only working with the selects within the cloned table row.  See this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fud4wej2/2/

I also tried to call `rowTemplate.remove()` after the `clone()`, thinking that the issue might have to do with duplicated ids, but to no avail.  Otherwise, to see the top pulldown being displayed correctly - showing `Foobar` as it's option - comment in the `return;` statement.

As is -- with `$(this).append(option);` commented out -- the top pulldown shows the second entry `WB-730-2` from `optionsToAdd` as its option.  If you comment in the final `$(this).append(option);` statement, the top pulldown has no options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines:

```
var option = $('option');
option.val(optionsToAdd[i]);
option.text(optionsToAdd[i]);
```

The `$('option')` function is evaluating that CSS selector in the scope of the whole document, which grabs *every* `option` tag on the page. This is causing your problem.

To fix:

```
var option = $('<option>');
```

This will parse the HTML and create a new option element.

Another alternative:

```
var option = $(document.createElement("option"));
```

Comment: I just found this myself.  Actually this question could be closed as no longer reproducible due to typographical error.  Thanks for the second set of eyes.